# EF Core Oracle FLOAT datatype mismatch

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I have some old Oracle 11g databases, that I am writing a .Net 6 EF Core utilities for.
In one of my tables, some columns are defined as FLOAT (Oracle seems to convert FLOAT to FLOAT(126)) and a few of these have the value 99000000000000000000000000000000000000 (9.9E37).

The exception I get is:

```
  System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
```

EF scaffolding created classes with decimal datatype for these which is a problem with decimal only supporting up to 7.9228E28. I have manually changed the datatype to double, as precision is not an issue here.

I guess I need to write a converter as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations), but I cannot make out which datatype to convert to double.

I did instruct EF Core to be Oracle 11 compatible:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(message => _logger.LogTrace(message));

        optionsBuilder.UseOracle(_connString, b => b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}
```

These are my package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.16">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.16">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.21.11" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/EFCoreREDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-4FF3A9A3-AE49-431B-A4FB-31F8C53FCCF5) you need to remove the FluentAPI `HasColumnType` configuration after changing the type to `double`.

Comment: I had a working solution where I considered the FLOAT as a string by Removing HasColumnType and added HasMaxLength(255) and IsUnicode(false) like it was for my other strings, and then added a HasConversion with a string converter.
Your soultion is so much cleaner.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time Oracle creates something unintuitive, but at least they have good documentation: always spend some extra time reading carefully!